# How to move multiple parts with attachments

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make something where when you move your mouse, a part moves

[image: arm]

When the mouse moves, I want this arm to move and have everything follow just using orientation (and stay at the center of certain parts)

This is my code for moving the parts

```lua
-- This is using remote events. This is local
game.ReplicatedStorage.JudgeCam2.OnClientEvent:Connect(function()
    game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable
    wait(.1)
    local TS = game:GetService("TweenService")
    TS:Create(game.Workspace.CurrentCamera, TweenInfo.new(.75,Enum.EasingStyle.Linear,Enum.EasingDirection.Out,0,false,0), {CFrame = game.Workspace.CamParts.JudgeCam2.CFrame}):Play()
    local GUN_ICON = "rbxasset://textures/GunCursor.png"
    local GUN_RELOAD_ICON = "rbxasset://textures/GunWaitCursor.png"
    
    mouse.Icon = GUN_ICON
    local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")
    local LastMousePos = nil  -- Used to calculate how far mouse has moved
    
    UIS.InputChanged:Connect(function(input, gameProcessedEvent)
        local CurrentMousePos1 = Vector2.new(mouse.X,mouse.Y)
        if gameProcessedEvent then return end
        if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseMovement then -- runs every time mouse is moved
            if LastMousePos == nil then
                game.ReplicatedStorage.MoveJudge2:FireServer(mouse,CurrentMousePos1,CurrentMousePos1)
            else
                game.ReplicatedStorage.MoveJudge2:FireServer(mouse,CurrentMousePos1,LastMousePos)
            end
            LastMousePos = CurrentMousePos1
        end
    end)

    UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(KeyCode)
        if KeyCode.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 and debouce2 == false then
            debouce2 = true
            mouse.Icon = GUN_RELOAD_ICON
            wait(6)
            debouce2 = false
        end
    end)
end)
-- This is the server
game.ReplicatedStorage.MoveJudge2.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr, mouse,CurrentMousePos,LastMousePos)
    print("(" .. tostring(CurrentMousePos) .. " - " .. tostring(LastMousePos) .. ")/5")
    local change = (CurrentMousePos - LastMousePos)/5 -- calculates distance mouse traveled (/5 to lower sensitivity)
    game.Workspace.Arm2.CFrame = game.Workspace.Arm2.CFrame * CFrame.Angles(0,math.rad(change.X),-math.rad(change.Y))
end)
```

Is there any way I can do this with positions or attactments?

Comment: what do you mean with "have everythig follow"?   what of https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/positioning-objects is unclear?

Comment: I am trying to make it so when the arm moves, everything else follows at the center like this https://imgur.com/a/uEaSJwP

Comment: But only one part actually moves even when I attach HingeConstraints

Comment: I don't see any arm. what is "follows at the center" supposed to mean? do you want to rotate several parts around a common axis? you could use a [WeldContraint](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/WeldConstraint) to stitch everything together

Comment: I will quickly try that.

Comment: It seems when the CFrame is changed, it still does not keep the offset (thats what I want).